# Can we calculate the pressure gradient impact on two cyclones with the Fujiwhara effect?

Tags: cyclone

If two cyclones come together and orbit each other as per the [Fujiwhara Effect](https://www.thoughtco.com/the-fujiwhara-effect-3443929)is there a way to calculate the change in pressure gradient that each will face?  If not, are there at least pressure gradient charts showing some previous cyclones that come together so that I could make an estimate of the changes?

Comment: I suggest you read the answer of this question first - https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/6491/have-two-hurricanes-ever-merged-and-what-was-the-result

Comment: @gansub  thanks, the Peito paper was very interesting.